# null error on removing a record from a store that is bound to a list

Tags: extjs

i have a list bound to a data store.  when i remove a record from that store i get an error at

```
dom.parentNode.removeChild(dom);

Ext.define.afterRemove (ext-all-debug.js:23908)
Ext.define.removeDocked (ext-all-debug.js:33183)
Ext.define.hideVerticalScroller (ext-all-debug.js:77741)
Ext.define.determineScrollbars (ext-all-debug.js:77651)
Ext.define.onViewRefresh (ext-all-debug.js:77869)
call (ext-all-debug.js:10472)
```

because dom.parentNode is null.  the dom object is a gridscroller and the event seems to be happening as some standard delayed layout refresh.

basically, this happens after i delete a record from a store that is bound to a list.

```
store.remove(rec);
store.sync();
```

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well, it looks like it was a bug in version 4.0.7 because 4.1 works.